# Using mounted volume for MySQL database in production

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I am pretty new to docker, and dockerizing my production application with docker swarm. The only way I found to manage my MySQL database in production is to use a mounted volume for the DB.

Is this the only way to manage DB? Or, is there a better or more secure way to manage production database?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a [docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) and mount the volume into the container.

Comment: This seems like the only way to manage the database. But, the next challenge is passing the DB config file to the container.

Comment: That's not difficult. You can add the db config during the container build step. It may even be possible to do it as an init script.